# How to add declare/sets and CTE in tableau desktop

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api, common-table-expression

I'm trying to insert a custom sql query that contains declares/sets and CTE. I've read alternatives like custom ODBC, wrapping it in a `select * from XX`, but neither worked.

This is the error I get when I try to insert my Microsoft SQL Server query (which works in MS SQL Server):
`[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'.`

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than pasting hand written SQL into Tableau, try modeling your data connection in the data source page and letting Tableau generate optimized SQL based on how you define your views. You'll have a better and faster experience. There are not that many situations where you need to write custom SQL in Tableau - say if you're calling a database specific function.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `Encoding` and `DriverUnicodeType`

```
[odbc_name]
...
Encoding=UTF8
DriverUnicodeType=1
```

furhtermore you might have version mismatch between your sql version and odbc driver.

Comment: where should I include this? Where could I update my odbc driver

Comment: If you are using windows. you need to check it from **ODBC Data Sources**

Comment: could you include a ScreenShot or more guidance please